# Treeview behaving differently when tapped than when clicked

Tags: vba, ms-access, treeview, touch, ms-access-2010

**The situation:**  I have an Access 2010 db that is meant to be deployed on a Windows 8 tablet.  The main form of the app contains a Treeview control.  Selecting a node on the Treeview sets the visibility of one of several subforms that are used for viewing/editing details of the selected node item.  I have a yes/no message box and some basic code on the BeforeUpdate event for each of the subforms.  So when the record on the subform is dirty and the user clicks anywhere on the main form (including anywhere in the Treeview control) this code is triggered.

**The problem:**  When the subform record is dirty and the user taps anywhere on the Treeview control, the message box pops up but cannot be interacted with because the app is busy.  Doing what, I don't know, but it stays that way until Access is shut down via Task Manager.  There is no code attached to the Treeview for anything but the Click event. This happens even when they touch white space in the Treeview below the existing nodes.

If the record is not dirty, everything works fine.

If the record is dirty and the user hits the "Save" button on the subform to trigger the BeforeUpdate event, everything works fine.

If the user taps a different control or in the empty space on the main form, the BeforeUpdate event is triggered and everything works fine.

If you plug a mouse into the tablet and do the same series of steps by clicking instead of tapping, everything works fine.

I've done a ton of searching and haven't been able to find anything relevant to this, so any suggestions or guidance to new places to look for suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

I've attached a sample of the BeforeUpdate code that exists on each of these subforms.  It's pretty basic, but maybe there's something in it that tapping and Treeviews just don't like.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
'If the form data has changed a message is shown asking if
'the changes should be saved. If the answer is no then
'the changes are undone

 On Error GoTo BeforeUpdate_Error

If Me.Dirty Then
'Add PropertyID, LPParentNodeID and TreeNodeID if Record is new

    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Me.PropertyID = Me.Parent!PropertyID
        Me.LPParentNodeID = Me.Parent!txtCurrKey
        Me.TreeNodeID = DateDiff("s", Date, Now())
    End If


'Display prompt to save the record
  If MsgBox("The record has changed - do you want to save it?", _
  vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Save Changes") = vbNo Then
     Me.Undo
  End If
End If

'If the record is still dirty, then record the change in the Audit table
If Me.Dirty Then
    Call AuditTrail(Me, InstanceID, PropertyID)
End If


BeforeUpdate_Exit:
   Exit Sub

BeforeUpdate_Error:
   MsgBox Err.Description
   Resume BeforeUpdate_Exit
End Sub
```

08/30/2013 Addition:  I forgot to mention the debugging behavior in the original question.  When I set a breakpoint on the BeforeUpdate Sub of the subform on any line from the actual Sub entry point down to the If statement with the message box, the code window comes up but the app again becomes busy, and I can't interact with either window.  Just like before, this behavior is unique to tapping that accursed Treeview control.

Comment: It sounds like you've covered your bases fairly well. You could try using a routine to write out debug messages to a text file to see at where in your code Access hangs, or last processes. It's tedious because you'll need a line of debug code after pretty much every line of code you posted. But it might help you figure out where the hang happens and you can then try to come up with a creative solution.

Comment: Tedious doesn't bother me. It's inherent to troubleshooting, in my opinion.  But your comment reminded me that I hadn't put the debugging behavior in the original question.  I have now.  Do you think writing it to text might give a better idea of where it is hanging?  With the breakpoint behavior listed above, my only clue has been that the users see that message box before it dies.

Comment: Very strange. I'd say I'm pretty much out of ideas. It does sound like some kind of bug in the ActiveX control or somewhere in Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is put a kind of edit/save structure into each of the subforms, whereby controls in the subform are locked until edit is clicked, and re-locked after save is clicked. So:

```
private sub bEdit()
    editMode true
end sub
private sub bSave()
    ...save logic
    editMode false
end sub
private sub editMode(isEdit as boolean)
    dim ctl as control
    for each ctl in me.controls
        if ctl.controltype is actextbox or ctl.controltype is accombobox then
            ctl.locked = (not isEdit)
        end if
    next
end sub
```

With this approach, it's then a small task to add editmode control for the parent form by adding

```
me.parent.editmode isEdit
```

to the end of of the editmode procedure.

In the parent form, editMode will need to be a PUBLIC sub.

In this sub, control whether the tree will do anything when clicked on:

```
public sub editMode(isEdit as boolean)
    tree.enabled = (not isEdit)
end sub
```